# not able to play audio from internet using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i  tried to play an audio file from internet using AVAudioplayer but there is no response from UIView but if i m to play an mp3 file from bundle it works ..cud u guys help me out below is the code...

```
-(IBAction)playPause:(id)sender
```

{

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.1040communications.net/sheeba/stepheni/iphone/images/today.mp3"];


NSError *error;
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
if (!player) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
[player prepareToPlay];

[player play];
```

}

Comment: Does the error checking code log anything? Isn’t the code simply waiting for the file to download?

Comment: yeah  i m getting this error....Error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -43.)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL has to be a file URL, see Apple’s [Technical QA1634](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1634/). You can download the file to the device and then play it locally.

Comment: mkay...is der any other example to stream audiofile to internet

Comment: There are [plenty examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ios+streaming+audio) of such code already on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

your url is not returning any data.That's why it is not playing.

Comment: I can see the file just fine.